# Calling the release/debug mode with "true/false" in command line

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a C++ program with lots of `.cpp` and `.h` files that requires creating a `Makefile`.

Now, I've been asked to accept two command line parameters in order to run the program (eg.. `./huntwumpus false`). The first one has to be the name of the program such as: `huntwumpus` and the second command line has to be either `true` (to enter the release mode) or `false` (to enter a debug mode).

My question is, how can I possibly do the true/false for switching modes within the command line? Do I have to link (somehow) within my `main()` function to test the command line with my `argc` and `argv`? or do I have to add some code in my `Makefile`?

Here is the `Makefile`:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++11
exe_file = huntwumpus
$(exe_file):bats.o event.o gold.o board.o room.o pit.o wumpus.o menu.o main.o
    $(CC) bats.o event.o gold.o board.o room.o pit.o wumpus.o menu.o main.o -o $(exe_file)
bats.o: bats.cpp
    $(CC) -c bats.cpp
event.o: event.cpp
    $(CC) -c event.cpp
gold.o: gold.cpp
    $(CC) -c gold.cpp
board.o: board.cpp
    $(CC) -c board.cpp
room.o: room.cpp
    $(CC) -c room.cpp
pit.o: pit.cpp
    $(CC) -c pit.cpp
wumpus.o: wumpus.cpp
    $(CC) -c wumpus.cpp
menu.o: menu.cpp
    $(CC) -c menu.cpp 
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o $(exe_file)
```

Comment: You don't need to humble yourself and go on about how you're "new". You do, however, need to help us out by showing what kind of `Makefile` you're working with and where you want to make changes. Could you use an environment variable with a default?

Comment: Debug vs release is something you need to decide before compiling your program, not when executing it.  Generally you would do this by passing a flag to the make command, i.e. `make DEBUG=true`, but the specifics will depend on how you've written your Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are required to pass it in the command line, this means you need a runtime debug mode. Thus no changes in the `Makefile` needed.

The easy solution is to simply have a global variable with the setting:

```
bool debug = false;
```

And then parse the arguments in your `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        // two arguments, so check the second
        const std::string second(argv[1]);
        if (second == "true") {
            // set debug mode
            debug = true;
        } else if (second == "false") {
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            // maybe do something if it's unknown
        }
    }

    // from here on you can simply use debug anywhere
    // else in your program, like so
    if (debug) {
        // something if in debug mode
    }
}
```

Comment: @vazza Don't mention it!

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are passed when you **run** the program; `./wumpus true` is like `ls -l`: you have a program, and one argument. `ls` changes its behavior based on the argument, just like your program can.

- At the most basic level, you could check if `argc == 2` (so you have exactly one argument) and then make a `std::string theargument(argv[1])` and work with that.
- `getopt()` and `getopt_long()` are commonly available.
- If you are using any other framework, check it (e.g. `QCommandLineParser`). There are plenty of available libraries to handle command-line options.

Comment: .. or, since Miles Budnek is better at reading the question than I am, do it at build time for debug/release mode, but that seems incompatible with the whole notion of "command-line argument"